Can someone explain the damage distribution on this aircraft that flew through a hailstorm?

An A320 flew into a hailstorm 20mins from landing. I’m intrigued by the damage distribution. Seems like everywhere else wasn't touched at all.  Why?

I'd love to see the engines of that plane

@Jpe61 Jet engines eat hail for lunch.

@reirab more like it is a requirement that they eat hail for lunch, and are specifically tested against them to make sure they do not fail. Engines that don't pass are not certified and cannot be used.

@Nelson Yep, that link is to the CFRs that specify the testing requirements for exactly that. :)

Props to that windshield tho

@AlanB like with the jet engines being able to suck up hail without stopping work, the windshield is designed to not shatter under heavy bombardment for the same reasons.  If it was smashed in the pilots would be getting hammered instead which would have far more serious consequences than just bad forward visibility while landing.

I posted this as a comment below, but there is considerable denting of the aluminum as well - the paint must adhere better to it than it does to fiberglass.  If you look along the right side of the aircraft as we see it at the line where the reflection changes from skybridge to open sky, you can see a number of dents from hail.  The same is true of the left side reflections, many of which should be straight lines but instead are all squiggly.  Presumably the entire forward facing aluminum surface is similarly dented, but the lighting in this image doesn't show the damage.

Fun fact: the affected plane is from the Austria Airlines, colloquially known as AUA. "Aua!" is also a colloquial exclamations in German indicating pain, similar to "ouch!" in English. So, when the pilots flew the AUA plane through the hailstorm, the AUA plane said: Aua!

Although the exterior of a jet airliner may just look like uniform aluminum with windows, the construction is actually much different than the outward appearance suggests.
The front of modern jet airliners are what's called a radome, which is a portmanteau of "radar" and "dome".  The radome houses a radar antenna, and the material covering the radome is much more fragile than the rest of exterior surface of the aircraft.  This is to improve the performance of the antenna.  Behind the radome is a structural wall that limits any impact to the radome's exterior from affecting the body of the aircraft.
This is why you see the exterior of the radome in such bad condition, but the rest of the aircraft's exterior in relatively such good condition.
Regarding the windshields, the forward windshield will almost always be exposed to the majority of weather-related impacts.  This is because the aircraft is flying in a forward direction (hopefully!), thus causing the greatest forces on those windows.  A simple way to think about this is to think about an automobile.  The front windshield of an automobile will be most affected by driving through hail, as opposed to any side windows.  When a vehicle (or aircraft) is not moving, however, impacts (and damage) will largely be determined by the installed angles of the windows.

@Bianfable Thank you for the edit... sorry it got deleted while I was editing at the same time, but I restored your improvement.  I'm done editing now, so feel free to make any other edits you like.

"to improve the performance of the antenna" is the understatement of the year. The radar wouldn't work at all if it was covered by metal (such as the aluminium skin used on the rest of the airframe), since metals are opaque to RF radiation. That's why the radome simply has to be plastic (fibreglass).

Do you have any idea why port portion of radome and port window got more damage than starboard side?

@user721108 best theory for biased damage is that the hail was falling at an agle due to winds higher up. So the plane was most likely flying straight, but the hail carried extra sideways velocity.

@TooTea But it is possible to make a fiberglass construction that would survive the hailstorm.. it would just be thick, and thus attenuate signals.

It would appear to me that once the radome had disintegrated, there would be violent radial airflow that would tend to carry a substantial proportion of the impactors away from the fuselage. That also applies to e.g. the leading edge of the wings: they have a strongly divergent radial airflow at all times.

@jpe61 So the hail was moving with the air, but the plane was side-slipping?

@DJohnM no the plane flies straight in its own mass of air. Hail on the other hand gained horizontal velocity before hitting the plane, when falling through an higher altitude layer of air moving sideways relative to the layer in which the plane flies. Hail kept some of that sideways velocity due to inertia, therefore hit the plane at an angle.

@DJohnM I suspect the other way around, but either one is possible. Planes are usually flown "dead straight" without sideslip for efficiency, except for short final in some cases, and flare of course. Conditions that produce hail of significant size usually also produce heavy windshear (thunderstorms), so the hail may have travelled a down in an air mass moving in direction x, and then fell into an airmass moving in direction y, and hit the airplane with residual horizontal speed from previous airmass.

Please note that the hail did not hit the aircraft, it was the other way around: plane flew into the hail at somewhere between 200 and 500 mph, hail falling at less than 100

@MikeB it's all about your reference frame. Einstein: "Does Oxford stop at this train?", or XKCD

@chrisH  No, not really. The point I was making is that the hail did not fall down across the plane to any meaningful extent, rather the plane flew horizontally through the hail, hence the strike pattern being very different from what people expect.

@MikeB that's exactly what reference frames mean in physics.  Motion is all relative. You're thinking in a ground reference frame, or that of the air.  The vectors add up to the same impact angle anyway, hence if looking out of the cockpit windscreen you'd see the hail coming directly towards you, with (little to) no sideways or vertical motion.

@ChrishH  I understand reference frames. But they are not relevant here. Many of the comments on this page talk about the hail 'falling' relative to the plane, which is basically incorrect, eg Jpe61

The windscreen.
As you can see from the photo, hailstones struck the forward windows almost perpendicularly, and the side windows almost parallel. The window material is layers of glass and plastic, and glass is hard and brittle, so impacts up to a certain force threshold will show no damage at all, then above that will cause cracking and cratering.
That's why the forward windows are beaten opaque while the side windows aren't even scratched. This is not surprising.
The port windscreen (right side in the photo) looks to be seconds from collapse. Even a small amount of glass striking the pilot in the face at 300Kts would be a serious distraction. I can only wonder how close this flight was to total loss.
The radome.
I don't know why the fiberglass radome took such damage while the surrounding aluminum seems totally unscathed. The visible damage seems to change suddenly at the boundary while AOA does not. Perhaps there are lots of little dents that don't show in the photo.
I am guessing that aluminum, being elastic and tough, dents upon impact and then springs back into shape. Fiberglass -- glass fibers embedded in resin -- being stiff and brittle, cracks upon similar impact. So aluminum recovers between multiple strikes (until metal fatigue sets in) while fiberglass accumulates damage.
Obviously the center of the radome, perpendicular to the hailstone attack, accumulated so much damage that it collapsed inward, allowing the pressure inside the antenna compartment to instantly rise to a titanic level and pop the radome like a party balloon. That's why most of the radome is missing instead of hanging there in shreds.
Then the hailstorm quickly battered the antenna itself into useless junk, concealing all its brother hailstorms from further detection by this particular aircraft.

LOL, "concealing all its brother hailstorms from further detection"

A couple of glass shards at 300kts might be distracting, but I think a bunch of never ending ice balls are even worse.

I strongly doubt the windows were close to collapsing inwards. It's much easier to prevent them from falling apart than building them in a way so they stay transparent on impacts.

I second the implications that the elasticity of the aluminum helped limit damage to it. Also, the point about the windows kind of applies to the rest of the skin of the aircraft as well, most of the impacts on the wings and fuselage would have been at comparatively shallow angles as well, so the amount of damage they could cause is more limited than any impacts on the radome. I would expect the leading edges of the wings to be a bit more beat-up than the rest of the plane for the same reason.

Composites can be quite brittle, so the hail would erode the surface (those dark patches? They reduce with the impact angle as you'd expect) and weaken the structure. Then once the radome started to crack, the airflow would try to tear it.

Hypothetically, with modern instruments and landing aids functioning, the crew could have landed the plane on a runway with zero external visibility, correct?

Aircraft aluminum is thicker than you might think. It most likely simply didn't dent at all. Remember that this stuff is designed to take an impact from a several-pound bird at 200-300 mph without noticeable damage and, more importantly, is designed to withstand the roughly 7.5 pounds of force per square inch (~0.5 kg/cm^2) attempting to blow the plane apart from the inside at any given time during cruise. The bag tags I have that are cut out of an airliner fuselage are about 1/8" (3 mm) thick. The ability to shrug off hail without damage is a design requirement.

Airplane windscreens are multilayer constructions.  The outermost layer is certainly heavily damaged, but the inner layers are still up to the task of keeping the wind out and the pressure in.

"allowing the pressure inside the antenna compartment to instantly rise to a titanic level and pop the radome like a party balloon", can you explain why this would be the case?
The radome is unpressurized, so I don't see what should cause a big pressure difference.
Also, there are plenty of cases where the radome just gets dented (without popping like a party balloon)

@Criggie that plane was in fact landed without complications: https://noe.orf.at/stories/3260642/ IDK how much visibility the pilots had left.

@ROIMaison the radome normally doesn't have any significant air pressure inside it. However, once it's cracked open, 2-300 MPH wind gets inside and, having nowhere else to go, builds pressure on the inside, which the radome isn't designed to withstand. F1 car bodies are built out of lightweight carbon fiber and can withstand 200MPH wind just fine. However, a little crack or chip will let the air in, and, with no place else to go, will rip bodywork right off without a second thought.

@Criggie BA Flight 009 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Airways_Flight_009) landed with an opaque windscreen and only lateral positioning guidance

@reirab If you look at the right side of the image, there is considerable denting of the aluminum visible.  You can see it along the line where the reflection switches from skybridge to sky.  I suspect that this picture wasn't taken to accentuate the damage to the hull but instead show the devastation of the radome and windscreen.  The same is true of the reflections on the image left, but less clearly.  If nothing else, these reflections should have lots of straight lines but they're all squiggly because of the dents.

@Jason Patterson: Well it's inconclusive but I think you may be right. If the aluminum really is dented, then the visible damage boundary may simply due to the fact that paint is easily chipped from the fiberglass but sticks to the deformed metal.

Oh, good catch @JasonPatterson! If you click to embiggen the image, you can see loads of wrinkles in the AL on the left side (as we see it) fanning out along the AL from where the remains of the radome attach (about 9 o'clock).

Just to add something to the other answers:
What it might have happened to the radome is that it has been damaged enough to loose its structural integrity and the missing piece(s) has just flown away.
Regarding the other parts of the aircraft, it is indeed very likely that also the fairing of the wing-fuselage attachment and the engine  cowlings got damaged like on this B777 but unfortunately without better/other pictures of the incident it's impossible to confirm that:

Note in this picture how the leading edge of the inlet has been also damaged: the leading edge of the wing and the rest of the nose might have suffered the same fate as well.

And look at how the angle changes to the right and left of the radome.  The hail would slip off at this point, and not go smashing in at 90º.  Other answers have kind of said this, but I think that's the primary difference at this particular part of the aircraft.

Good find with those photos.  Does the source indicate if there is any structural damage there, or primarily cosmetic (and, of course, reduced performance)?
